# understanding timestamp from blockexplorer.com

Tags: block, hash, timestamp

What is the timestamp used for the blocks on blockexplorer.com 
For example block 233969 has: 
**Time: 2013-04-30 23:27:36**

is this time converted to 32bit hex for hash calculation, if so how ?

Answer (score 1):

In the network protocol, times are represented as [Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) stored as *unsigned* 32-bit integers.

> is this time converted to 32bit hex for hash calculation, if so how ?

Bitcoin uses a binary protocol. Nothing is hex. When viewing the binary data, your tools may *display* the data in hex, but you can't directly use these hex characters for hashing, etc.